# SharePoint PowerShell Script deployment. Only errors outside of Visual Studio?

Tags: powershell, solution-package, solution-deployment

I have a problem regarding deployment of WSP package. I develop the solution using Visual Studio and use No Activation + a PowerShell script as 'post-deployment' command. The PowerShell script is the one that has scripts for Enable-SPFeature.

Weird thing is, if I package the WSP file and use Windows Powershell **outside** of Visual Studio, it suddenly throws an error when activating features (like the column is not found, the webpart is not registered as safe, etc).

I don't get this, because the scripts are the same. Am I missing something here?

Thank you!

Update:

Also, it seems that if I activate using Enable-SPFeature, it doesn't work properly, but if I activate manually it works! This is really weird.

Comment: which version of sharepoint you are using?

Comment: could you please share the complete error details/ screen shot to understand the issue...also share teh script.

Comment: Thanks Hardik and Waqas! I'm using SharePoint 2010. 

I think I found what the error was.. on initial run of the script, I was using the wrong WSP file. I corrected the file location, but didn't restart Powershell. Once I run again it throws error.

Once I restarted powershell and got the correct file, it doesn't throw error anymore. I think it also has something to do with site.dispose and web.dispose.

Can you share more if there are any other things I need to be careful about?